# Conditional executes when presented with a value from a forEach or loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects

I have a data structure:

```
var videos = {
    'a': [
        {
            'name': 'a',
            'src': 'https://foo/video/',
            'thumb': 'images/foo.png'
        },
        {
            'name': 'b',
            'src': 'https://bar/video/',
            'thumb': 'images/bar-10.png'

        },
        {
            'name': 'c',
            'src': 'https://baz/video/',
            'thumb': 'images/baz.png'
        }
    ],
    'b': [
        {
            'name': 'a',
            'src': 'https://fizz/video/',
            'thumb': 'images/fiz.png'

        },
        {
            'name': 'b',
            'src': 'https://buzz/video/',
            'thumb': 'images/buzz.png'

        },
        {
            'name': 'c',
            'src': 'https://blargh/video/',
            'thumb': 'images/blargh.png'


        }
    ]
};
```

Which I am storing its keys in an array:

```
var videoNames = Object.keys(videos); // 'a', 'b'

  var containerFluidSecondary = document.getElementById('container-fluid--secondary');

containerFluidSecondary.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(function (section, i) {
```

I'm then going into the DOM and checking to see if any of the section tags and the classNames they have match the keys in the array i.e. videoNames

```
        if (videoNames[i].match(section.className)) {
              ...do something
        }
    })
```

But i'd like the conditional to react if there was more than one class in the DOM...

So if there were 4 instances of the class `a` in the DOM it would execute 4 times!

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I would up doing a `console.log` on:

```
console.log('section.className',section.className)
```

and indeed I get:

```
index.html:317 section.className a
index.html:317 section.className b
index.html:317 section.className c
index.html:317 section.className d
index.html:317 section.className a
```

So I would expect this:

```
containerFluidSecondary.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(function (section, i) {
        console.log('section.className',section.className)
        if (section.classList.contains(videoNames[i])) {
         var videoContainer = [...section.getElementsByClassName('video-container')[0].children];
          var vids = videos[section.className];

            videoContainer.forEach(function (img, i) {
             img.src = vids[i].thumb

             img.addEventListener('click', function(){
               section.querySelector('iframe').src = vids[i].src
             },false);
            })
       }
    })
```

to fire twice for `a` and once for `b`

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [classList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which will return `true` if any of the classes of the element match the passed class name:

```
    if (section.classList.contains(videoNames[i])) {
          ...do something
    }
```

Comment: Logically I would think that would work after reading the docs for it. But It just maintained what I already had.